# Using `xarray.apply_ufunc` with `np.linalg.pinv` returns an error with `dask.array`

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I get an error when running the following MWE:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import pinv
import dask

data = np.random.randn(4, 4, 3, 2)

da = xr.DataArray(data=data, dims=("x", "y", "i", "j"),)

da = da.chunk(x=1, y=1)
da_inv = xr.apply_ufunc(pinv, da,
                        input_core_dims=[["i", "j"]],
                        output_core_dims=[["i", "j"]],
                        exclude_dims=set(("i", "j")),
                        dask = "parallelized",
                        )
```

This throws me this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glade/scratch/tomasc/tracer_inversion2/mwe.py", line 14, in <module>
    da_inv = xr.apply_ufunc(pinv, da,
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py", line 1204, in apply_ufunc
    return apply_dataarray_vfunc(
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py", line 315, in apply_dataarray_vfunc
    result_var = func(*data_vars)
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py", line 771, in apply_variable_ufunc
    result_data = func(*input_data)
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py", line 747, in func
    res = da.apply_gufunc(
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/array/gufunc.py", line 489, in apply_gufunc
    core_output_shape = tuple(core_shapes[d] for d in ocd)
  File "/glade/u/home/tomasc/miniconda3/envs/py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/array/gufunc.py", line 489, in <genexpr>
    core_output_shape = tuple(core_shapes[d] for d in ocd)
KeyError: 'dim0'
```

Even though when using `dask.array.map_blocks` directly, things seem to work right out of the box:

```py
data_inv = dask.array.map_blocks(pinv, da.data).compute() # works!
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Same question [answered on the xarray repository here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/discussions/7503).)

You were almost there, you just needed to add the sizes of new the output dimensions by including the kwarg

```py
dask_gufunc_kwargs={'output_sizes': {'i': 2, 'j': 3}}
```

It does sort of say this in the docstring for `apply_ufunc` but it could definitely be clearer!

That's a very unhelpful error, but it's ultimately being thrown because the keys `'i'` and `'j'` don't exist in the dict of expected sizes of the output (because you didn't provide them).

The actual [error message has been improved](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/7509) in xarray version v2023.2.0.